# How to use XLD's "import tags from a text [file]" feature

Tags: software, import, audio

I have a batch of AIFF files I am trying to transcode to mp3 and tag using [XLD](https://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html) (X Lossless Decoder). I have all the tag metadata in a text file like so:

```
01 AUDIO "Package" "Peter Howard"
02 AUDIO "Nirvana" "Martin Figura"
03 AUDIO "Fresh Meat" "Andrea Porter"
04 AUDIO "The Shout" "André Mangeot"
…
```

Where that format of each line is:

`[track number] AUDIO "[track name]" "[Artist]"`

I'm trying to use the "File > Import Tags From a Text" feature in the following way:

1. File > Open folder as disc (I have all the `.aiff`s in a folder).
2. File > Import Tags From a Text.
3. Paste in the block of data from above into the main pane.
4. Use the following "Format": `%n AUDIO "%t" "%a"` (i.e. the same as above)
5. Match with: Track Number. Overwrite existing tags = yes.
6. Select all tracks in the main window.
7. Click Apply.

Nothing happens at this point, but I don't know if I've got the format string wrong, or if I'm using the whole feature incorrectly.  There isn't any documentation on the website, and I've tried reading the source code but can't make head or tale of it.  There are the same number of lines in the text block as there are tracks.  I've tried with 1- and 2-digit track numbers. I've tried with and without a trailing newline.

Does anyone have any experience with this application and this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s possible to import multiple metadata fields with just a single dataset in a single action. To do so, write down the metadata as a CSV-like formatted text, e.g.:

TRACKNUMER`Tab`ARTIST`Tab`TITLE`Tab`COMPOSER`Enter`
TRACKNUMER`Tab`ARTIST`Tab`TITLE`Tab`COMPOSER`Enter`
…

Then Copy and Paste it into XLD´s Metadata Text Import Dialog.

For the format string use:

```
%n  %a  %t  %c
```

To create the `Tab` character by yourself in XLD´s Import Dialog format definition, use the key combination <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> instead of just `Tab`.

An alternative approach is to use any other character that is not contained in your metadata as a field separator, e.g. @@, and use it instead of the horizontal `Tab`.

Comment: This is a better answer, I think!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, by some trial and error: it seems the pattern matching isn't too sophisticated, so I tried it in multiple passes.  In other words, first set the artist by using the text:

```
01 Peter Howard
02 Martin Figura
03 Andrea Porter
04 André Mangeot
…
```

and the format string `%n %a` (other steps the same).  Then set the track names using the text:

```
01 Package
02 Nirvana
03 Fresh Meat
04 The Shout
```

and the format string `%n %t`.  And so on.

In each case, clicking "Apply" changes the tags in the selected tracks. You can proceed with transcoding after you're done setting the tags.